# Google Drive API and Python Uploading Media to Shared Drive

Tags: python, google-drive-api, upload

I am downloading attachments from Jira tickets and uploading them to our Google Drive using Google's API modules. The file is not getting pushed to the shared drive folder but to my personal one.

Here is my relevant code:

`

```
if dictGoogleServices["success"] == True:

    try:

        driveService = dictGoogleServices["drive-service"]
        for dictIssue in lstIssues: #passed in list of dictionaries that contain issue data
            
            #create issue folder
            folderData = gm.createFolderInGDrive(driveService, dictIssue['key'], googleDriveParentId)
            
            #create assets folder
            assetFolderData = gm.createFolderInGDrive(driveService, "assets", folderData["id"])

            #update folder permissions
        
    driveService.permissions().create(fileId=folderData["id"], supportsAllDrives=True, body={"role": "reader", "type": "anyone"}).execute()
        
 driveService.permissions().create(fileId=assetFolderData["id"], supportsAllDrives=True, body={"role": "reader", "type": "anyone"}).execute()

            dictAttachments = dictIssue["attachments"]
        for idx in dictIssue["attachments"]:
            dictAttachment = dictAttachments[idx]

                #doing this because google api kept throwing a file didn't exist error when pointing to the file in our atlassian cloud - delete file after success
                #download attachment to desktop
            r = requests.get(dictAttachment["jira-path"], auth=("xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.com", "(xxxxxxxxx)"), stream=True)
            path = os.path.expanduser("Desktop/holding-cell/")
        storedPath = join(path, dictAttachment['filename'])
        file = open(storedPath,'w')   
        file.close()

                #get mimetype of file
        mimeType = None
            mimeType = mimetypes.guess_type(storedPath)[0] 
                    
        if mimeType != None: 
                        
            #make sure the attached file exists
            if os.path.exists(storedPath) == True:

                        #call upload file method in our google manager module
                gm.uploadFileToGDrive(driveService, dictAttachment['filename'], storedPath, mimeType, [assetFolderData["id"]], assetFolderData["driveId"])
            else: 
                print(f"{cm.WARNING}File {dictAttachment['filename']} does not exist\n{storedPath}{cm.ENDC}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"{cm.WARNING}There was an issue moving {dictIssue['key']} to GDrive\n{e}{cm.ENDC}")
```

`

and in our Google Manager module:

`

```
def uploadFileToGDrive(self, driveService, filename, filepath, mimetype, parentFolderId, driveId): 

    try: 

         fileMetaData = {'name': filename, 'mimeType': mimetype, 'parents': [driveId]}
         media = MediaFileUpload(filepath, mimetype=mimetype)
         results = driveService.files().create(body=fileMetaData, media_body=media, fields='id', supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
         print(results)

    except Exception as e:

         print(f"{cm.WARNING}There was an error moving the file {filepath} to the folder {parentFolderId} on GDrive\n{e}{cm.ENDC}")
```

`

So the file ends up in the right shared drive if I pass in driveId to the parents param. But if I pass in the parentFolderId (which is the id of the assets folder I created) it ends up in my personal drive. How can I get it in the correct folder in the shared drive. For clarity the hierarchy is like so:

shared-drive
jira-issue-folder
asset folder <--want the file here.

Comment: About `But if I pass in the parentFolderId (which is the id of the assets folder I created) it ends up in my personal drive.`, in your script, it seems that `parentFolderId` is not used. How about this?

Comment: Sorry, i should have been clearer, the script posted uses driveId because that's the only writing of it that gets the file into the right drive, if I swap driveId with parentFolderId the file ends up in my personal drive.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, you want to use `fileMetaData = {'name': filename, 'mimeType': mimetype, 'parents': [parentFolderId]}`. Is my understanding correct? By the way, what is different between `driveId` and `parentFolderId`?

Comment: parentFolderId is the id of the folder named "assets" where I want to store the uploaded file, driveId is the shared drive where the assets folder resides. The hierarchy is like so Drive-->Folder1-->assets-->file

As for the first question, I'd like to use whatever works : ) I assumed how you wrote fileMetaData in your response would work but it is not.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understood that `parentFolderId` is the folder ID of the folder in a shared drive. In this case, I think that your script of `results = driveService.files().create(body=fileMetaData, media_body=media, fields='id', supportsAllDrives=True).execute()` with `fileMetaData = {'name': filename, 'mimeType': mimetype, 'parents': [parentFolderId]}` can create a file into the folder of `parentFolderId`. For example, how about confirming `parentFolderId` again?